# Robinhood API Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm having something strange happen with the Robinhood API. Specifically with getting all of the options instruments (just data about the options). The code below is part of my program

```python
def get_options_instruments(self):

        params = {
        "chain_symbol" : "AMD",
        "chain_id" : "e66ce029-db96-4572-87a0-b144613c08bf",
        "type": "call",
        "state": "active",
        "tradability": "tradable",
        "strike_price" : "16.0000",
        "expiration_date": "2018-10-19"
        }


        #API_URLS['option-instrument']= "https://api.robinhood.com/options/instruments/"
        response = self.login_session.get(API_URLS['option-instrument'],params = params)
        response = response.json()["results"]
        print(json.dumps(response,indent = 4,separators=(',', ': ')))#'option-instrument'       : "https://api.robinhood.com/options/instruments/",
```

All parameters seem to have an effect when receiving the option instruments EXCEPT expiration date (which is the most one of the important parameters that I need to use). Below is a sample response of an option instrument.

```
{
    "issue_date": "1987-01-12",
    "strike_price": "16.0000",
    "url": "https://api.robinhood.com/options/instruments/3cb75cca-0987-46d7-bff1-20cadfb74a83/",
    "expiration_date": "2018-07-20",
    "tradability": "tradable",
    "chain_id": "e66ce029-db96-4572-87a0-b144613c08bf",
    "updated_at": "2018-06-03T00:16:56.985489Z",
    "min_ticks": {
        "cutoff_price": "3.00",
        "below_tick": "0.01",
        "above_tick": "0.05"
    },
    "state": "active",
    "id": "3cb75cca-0987-46d7-bff1-20cadfb74a83",
    "chain_symbol": "AMD",
    "type": "call",
    "created_at": "2017-11-18T04:15:17.795113Z"
}
```

I'm just wondering if anybody has any idea why something like this might happen? Could it perhaps be something on the API's side and not mine? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"expiration_dates"` instead and it will work.

I encountered this issue recently as well, where specifying parameters for the `"expiration_date"` field yielded nothing.